# Unable to link Java program to SQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I've been attempting to implement a JDBC based database connection in my Java program to any database management systems. First I tried using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, my code looked like this:

```
public class ConnectionCreate {
    public connectionCreate(){
        try {
            //SQL Server Manager Settings
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test","test","test" );
            System.out.println("Connection Established");

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My test database was called test, hosted on port 1433 in SQL Server Management Studio and said it was running. I could modify it through the Studio GUI, adding tables etc but whenever I called my Java code it would fail saying:

```
  Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Invalid argument: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.
```

I've checked everything I can think to, the jar file is definitely being found for JDBC library as there's no issue with the Class.forName call. I've been on SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols and I've ensured all connection types are enabled including TCP/IP. I've made sure the default port to use is 1433. I've even totally disabled my Firewall just incase and still it refuses to work.

Out of desperation I've also tried a different database management tool. XAMPP using PhpmyAdmin and mysql. I've once again attached the necessary .jar correctly, insured it runs fine locally in my web browser and used the following code in my Java test script:

```
public class ConnectionCreate {
    public connectionCreate(){
        try {
            //MySQL Settings
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
            System.out.println("Connection Established");

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This also gives me an error when I run my Java test program. It states:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I'm at a complete loss of what to do here, I can't seem to establish any working database connection in my Java program, and I'm not sure what else I could need to change on my system or with my code to make it work. 
Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you replicate this with a very simple program that just connects? Just to confirm that that it's not an issue in some other part of the program? There a very very simple program for JDBC here you can test with:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100

Answer (score 0):

I see that the SQL Server on the same machine.

I think you need to check in the SQL Server Configuration manager if you've enabled access via TCP/IP as there is a native (non TCP/IP) protocol available that SSMS can use.

See TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I've followed that tutorial before and I made sure on my database that TCP/IP is enabled, the post to listen on defaults to 1433 and my Java tries to use these settings. It still doesn't work however and I receive the same error as before stating "Invalid argument: connect"